# JERSEY Project Maven Configuration Problem with pom.xml

Tags: java, rest, maven, configuration, jersey

I have started learning REST web services and trying to configure my first maven jersey project. I have selected jersey-quickstart-webapp v.2.16. And my pom.xml file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.khal</groupId>
<artifactId>messenger</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>messenger</name>

<build>
    <finalName>messenger</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

First line is showing the fallowing error

```
Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer
```

Is something wrong with my Maven project?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Maven version is 3.63

Comment: Any reason you use Java 7?

Comment: No, Java version I am working on is 16.

Comment: I do not think Jersey 2.16 works with JDK 1.6. I do not think Jersey 2.16 works with JDK 16 either.

Comment: Oh! What's the appropriate version I should be using?